# Learn Linux Application programming by Example Applications

Tags: linux

After studying the basics of Linux Application Programming, the next step is to learn the different ways in which the programming concepts like fork, threads, IPC mechanism etc are used in real applications.

Please guide on how to master these concepts using real applications?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials about this in the net.

Comment: @KirilKirov: I am not talking about the tutorials. Its one thing to learn the concepts, but it is still another things to apply those concepts. I am particularly looking for some simple easy to learn applications where these concepts are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand what a particular program (e.g. a usual command like `ls` or `date` ...) does in term of [*system calls*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), try using `strace` on it, e.g.

```
strace ls
```

Another major point is that most of GNU/Linux is [**free software**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) so you can study its source code (even run it with a debugger) and improve it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're exactly targeting, but this book is a classic if you are programming on *nix:

```
Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment (2nd Edition)
SBN-10:  0201433079
ISBN-13: 978-0201433074
```

HTH

Comment: I am not looking for a book. I want to look through actual application which are not so complex but contains essential concepts to master

Comment: Infact i learned the linux application programming from the same book itself.

Comment: @LinuxPenseur "I want to look through actual application which are not so complex but contains essential concepts to master" Which you can find in a book... Looking into an actual application to learn something is not the way to go (IMHO). I would rather learn the concepts then try to understand an actual application.